# How to make a string (str) for python value

Tags: python, string

i want to turn "a" to value. like:

```
"a" = 8
```

How do I "take down" the quotes and make it as value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `globals()['a'] = 8` though there are usually better solutions for this. Also `exec('a = 8')` works, but don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but in Python 3 it isn't possible to assign a value to a string...

Comment: I think the author meant to assign a value to a variable with a name a. This could be beneficial, when you would like to create strings a,b,c,d, ... and assign different values to them, based on their names.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal can not be changed. Nor can a str value of any sort. Even strings stored in values such as:

```
a = "some string"
```

The string itself "some string" can not be changed. What the identifier a is bound to can be changed though:

```
a = "some other string"
```

But no string has been changed. We just changed what object the identifier a refers to.